# JavaFX window sizing

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, javafx

My app looks different at same OS. This is `Windows 7` rich interface:

[image]

And `Windows 7` regular interface:

[image]

The only thing that makes me angry is sizing. In FXML it's `640x445`, but Windows 7 makes it wider. How can I avoid that? Is there an approach to make `TextArea` fullscreen or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize your stage at initialize you can use following code (i assume you use javafx-2?)

```
//stage.setResizable(true);

Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();    
Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
```

or you can use fullscreen mode:

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```