# Set background image the same size as the window/screen in Java app

Tags: java, css, image, background, javafx

I would like to set a background image the same size as my window/screen.

I would *prefer* to do this in my `CSS` file, but I have ***NOT FOUND*** a way to accomplish this.

Must I do this in a javafx class file?

Thanks for every help ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to determine the **screen size in java code** as demonstrated in [JavaFX window sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491944/javafx-window-sizing), there is no way to determine it in CSS.

For an Image, in your java code you can use something as

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
imageView.setFitWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
imageView.setFitHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight());
```

If you want to set the background image to a scene then:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class ScreenSizeImage extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
        // uncomment if you want the stage full screen.
        //stage.setFullScreen(true);

        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

        stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-image: url(" +
                "'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-box-icon.png'" +
            "); " +
            "-fx-background-size: cover;"
        );
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Of course, rather than the inline setStyle call you are best off using a separate CSS stylesheet like below:

```
.root{
    -fx-background-image: url("background_image.jpg");
    -fx-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Good question...

- Firstly, I think you mean "the size of your app window" in your question.  Obviously, you can't have a background image that is larger than your screen if you app window is smaller.
- Secondly, here's a snippet from the **JavaFX CSS Reference Guide:**

  [**http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html**](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

  > > ***"...the background and border mechanisms are patterned after the CSS 3 draft backgrounds and borders module. See [4] for a detailed description.***"
  > >
  > > > ```
  > > >    ...
  > > > ```
  > >
  > > [4] CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3: **http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/**

  ---

  - You can use the JavaFX *vendor specific* CSS property `-fx-background-size` with the **`stretch`** value as long as your aspect ratio is correct/your dimensions are proportional.
  - You might also get it to work by trying a combination of `auto` for one dimension and `100%` for another... and some combination of `contain`... depending on if you can live with a *cropped image*.
  - > ***`-fx-background-size`***`<bg-size> [ , <bg-size> ]*`
    >
    > > `<bg-size> = [ <size> | auto ]{1,2} | cover | contain | stretch`
    > >
    > > A series of  values separated by commas. Each bg-size item in the series applies to the corresponding image in the background-image series.
  - You can get **more detail** at [**http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image)