# Background not centered when using -fx-background-size: cover with -fx-background-position: center center

Tags: java, css, javafx, background, background-size

I have successfully set a background image on a `BorderPane` in an FXML using CSS linked in my JavaFX project. However, using `cover` sticks the top-left corner of the background image to the top-left corner of the `BorderPane`. Cover itself scales the image well, but the image is not centered like it should be.

I have found multiple questions and answers saying you need to use `-fx-background-position: center center;` but it hasn't helped me at all. I implemented it in every position of my CSS, and also directly in FXML, without any success. I tried using options other than `cover`, such as `auto`, and they do center the background, but they crop the image instead of scaling it the way `cover` does.

Relevant parts of my code are as follows.

CSS:

```
#login{
    -fx-background-image: url("login-background.jpeg");
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-size: cover;
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<BorderPane fx:id="localRoot" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="...">
   <center>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            .
            .
            .
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Java:

```
@FXML
private BorderPane localRoot;

public void initialize() {
    localRoot.setId("login");
}
```

Comment: Use a `StackPane` as the root node for the `center`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I am not quite sure what exactly you meant. I replaced the `BorderPane` with a `StackPane`, set the ID to it and the background image loaded properly, but it was still not centered. Would you mind writing a few lines of code to help me? Thanks :)

Comment: `BorderPane` has a `setCenter` method. If you are using `SceneBuilder`, you should see where you can set the center of the `BorderPane`. The `BorderPane`'s center root node should be set to `StackPane`. Then add your `HBox` to the `StackPane`.

Comment: Post your complete `FXML` file.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I am adding the FXML's now. Sorry about the delay, I was finishing another part of the same project.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson FXML's added. This entire project is on GitHub, I can share the link if you are interested, instead of posting more code here.

Comment: It looks centered on my screen. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Add the `GitHub` link.

Comment: The only `ImageView` I see is to the left of "Library". Is this supposed to be the background Image?

Comment: Okay, so you are trying to set the background image through `CSS`. If you post the `GitHub` link, I can probably find a fix.

Comment: I suggest you try one of these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515172/set-background-image-the-same-size-as-the-window-screen-in-java-app). I would start with the one that references the `JavaFX CSS Reference Guide`

Comment: What I would do to solve this problem is set the width and height of the `Scene` and not allow resizing.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Unfortunately none of those fixes helped me, and not allowing resizing just wouldn't work for me. I am using the sam concept throughout the project and I need it to be resizable. 
It seems like one of my friends managed to fix it by implementing a whole new class with listeners. If you are interested in that, I can share another GitHub link or wait until we finish implementing it in our project. Anyways, thanks you very much :)

Comment: I am glad you found a fix.