# JavaFx: How to make the background image size change with the window when increasing/decreasing the window size?

Tags: java, image, user-interface, javafx, background-image

How would I be able to set the background image to the size of the window when increasing or decreasing the window frame? Right now the image is a set size of 300,300 so when increasing the window the size stays the same. 
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, nameInput, passLabel, passInput, 
    loginButton);

    grid.setMinSize(300,300);
    grid.setMaxSize(300,300);
    StackPane root = new StackPane(grid);
    NumberBinding maxScale = Bindings.min(root.widthProperty().divide(300), 
    root.heightProperty().divide(300));
    grid.scaleXProperty().bind(maxScale);
    grid.scaleYProperty().bind(maxScale);

    BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("image.jpg", 300, 300, 
    false, true),
    BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, 
    BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
    //then you set to your node
    grid.setBackground(new Background(myBI));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,300);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515172/set-background-image-the-same-size-as-the-window-screen-in-java-app

Answer (score 0):

You can try to instantiate a BackgroundSize object according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html#isCover--) and set the cover value to true. Then instead of using `BackGroundSize.DEFAULT`, use the BackGroundSize object you created.